Get an object from a string variable with the object name
Is there a way to get an object using the object name (also given from a function variable)?
I'm saying if you give a variable as function input, is there a way to get the object with the variable name?
I don't know if I explained myself well.
See the code sample to be more exhaustive:
function testFunction(objectname_as_string){
   objectname_as_string.property = 'value'; //this is not working well because this way it's like assigning a property to a string
} 

objectname_as_string it's not an object, but it's only the string with the object name.
The object was previously declared with
var animal = {};

In this case if you want an object called 'animal' do:
testFunction('animal'); //it doesn't work for the reason explained in the code comment above

So how to get a object from a string with object name and then work on the object with the given variable name?

Are you looking for someObject[value] ?

Just… don't. Either pass the actual object to the function (testFunction(animal)), or create a "registry" for your objects like const objs = { animal: {} } from where you can access them simply via objs['animal']. Looking up variables by name is madness.
